# Certificate validation - GetCertHashString vs GetPublicKeyString

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate

I have a C# application (.Net Framework 4.7) that authenticates an SSL certificate by comparing the certificate's public thumbprint (stored as a constant in the code) with the value returned by `X509Certificate.GetCertHashString()`.

```
httpObj.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateCertificate);
...
private static bool ValidateCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
{
    return certificate.GetCertHashString().ToLower() == HASH_CONSTANT;
}
```

I would like to know what the recommended practice is to avoid having to update the hash string constant and re-release the application every time the certificate is renewed.

[This post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80722/does-renewing-ssl-certificate-change-its-thumbprint-fingerprint) suggests `GetPublicKeyString` will return the same value after the certificate is renewed, but `GetCertHashString` will return the new certificate hash.

Are there any disadvantages in authenticating against the public key instead of the certificate hash?

Another possible candidte in the X509Certificate class is `GetSerialNumberString`.

Comment: I wouldn't use any of mentioned. For server certificate validation I would use a combination of Issuer and DnsName value in SAN extension. For user client certificates I would use a combination of UPN value in SAN extension and Issuer. These are enough reliable.

Comment: `GetPublicKeyString()` only returns the same answer on a newer cert if "renew with the same key" was chosen.  That's generally considered bad a practice, so really they're both different on new certs.